# Project screen position onto plane in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, transformation, raytracing, plane

I'm currently struggling with a simple task: Given a mouse position on the screen, calculate the new position which is determined by calculating the intersection of the camera plane that goes through the selected object and the ray of the mouse click.

The math involved is not that tricky but still I can't seem to find the error.

```
        QVector3D cameraPosition = Rotation.rotatedVector(translation);
        QVector3D cameraDirection = Dir;
        QVector3D objectPosition = objectTranslation;
        QVector3D up = Rotation.rotatedVector(QVector3D(0,1,0));
        QVector3D Right = QVector3D::crossProduct(Dir, up);
```

As you can see, I'm using Qt to represent my data. First of all, I rotate my translation Vector by the Camera Rotation to obtain the cameraPosition. Otherwise I won't get the cameraPosition in Worldcoordinates. After that I calculate the Up and Right Vector. In order to calculate the ray-plane intersection I'm using this as a reference: http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0104/algorithm_0104B.htm#Line-Plane Intersection

Afterwords I normalize the screen coordiantes

```
        float screen_x = 2*(float(pos.x())/width()-0.5);
        float screen_y = 2*((float(height()-1-pos.y())/height())-0.5);
        screen_x*= (1.0f/height())/(1.0f/width());
```

Finally, the actual computation:

```
        QVector3D P0 = cameraPosition;
        QVector3D n = cameraDirection;
        QVector3D V0 = objectPosition;
        QVector3D u = (screen_x*Right+screen_y*up)*0.5+cameraDirection;
        float s = QVector3D::dotProduct(n, V0-P0) / QVector3D::dotProduct(n, u);
        objectTranslation = P0+s*u;
```

I guess the problem lies withing the calculation of u or something beyond me. I get the Direction of the camera by evaluation the ModelView Transformation matrix and taking out the third row:

```
GLdouble modelview[16];
glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
QMatrix4x4 mv = QMatrix4x4(modelview);
Dir = QVector3D(mv.row(2).x(), mv.row(2).y(), mv.row(2).z()).normalized();
```

Comment: You do not take the projection matrix into account. When using an orthographic projection, you can get away with just some scaling, but if you use a perspective projection, it's not going to work that way. In any case, you could just use the inverse of the projection matrix to project your screen space point (after converting it to normalized device coordinates) back to eye space.

Comment: @derhass: I'm not sure why I need the projection matrix at all. I have everything I need to calculate the projected point. The only thing that I seem not to calculate correctly is the Up and Right Vector. Everything else should be there. Also, when projecting a point into 3D space, you get a line, so there has to be some kind of projection going on, I don't see how this can be achieved by multiplying with the inverse of the projection matrix.

I will give it a try with the method you described.

Comment: Okay, I now have the point in eye coordinates aka
QVector3D eyePoint = invProj * QVector3D(screen_x, screen_y, 0);

What now? How can I reuse the above code? Am I right that I have to add the cameraPosition to the eyePoint in Order to get the world coordinates of the point?